# CSS selector last-child vs last

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a snippet here:

```js
$('#add').click(function(){
    $('#list').after("<div class='container-editor'><p>some text inside</p><p>some text inside</p><p>some text inside</p></div>");
});

$('#remove').click(function(){
    $('.container-editor:last-child').remove();
});
```

```css
.container-editor {
    padding: .5em 2em 1.5em;
    margin-top: 10px;
    box-shadow: 1px 0 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='list'>
    <div class='container-editor'>
        <p>some text inside</p>
        <p>some text inside</p>
        <p>some text inside</p>
    </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<button id='add'>add</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button id='remove'>remove</button>
```

By clicking on the add button, a new div is appended to the end. By clicking on the remove button, the last '.container-editor' element is removed.

However, the remove button in the JsFiddle linked above only works once.

If I change the following code:

```
$('.container-editor:last-child').remove();
```

to

```
$('.container-editor:last').remove();
```

Then, the remove button works multiple times.

My questions is why does the `:last-child` selector stops working after an element is removed? This effect is not stated in the [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_last.asp)

---

Update: Thanks for all your inputs. Yes, I made a mistake using `after` instead of `insert`. But still, thanks to @T.J. Crowder, it is good to know that:

.container-editor:last-child means select the last child of class `container-editor` in their parent element.

:last doesn't care about parents, it will just select the last one.

I added this new snippet to illustrate the unique part about `.container-editor:last-child`

```js
$('#remove').click(function(){
    $('.container-editor:last-child').remove();
});
```

```css
.container-editor {
    padding: .5em 2em 1.5em;
    margin-top: 10px;
    box-shadow: 1px 0 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='container-editor'>
  <p>some text inside</p>
  <p>some text inside</p>
  <p>some text inside</p>
</div>

<div class='container-editor'>
  <p>some text inside</p>
  <p>some text inside</p>
  <p>some text inside</p>
</div>

<div class='container-editor'>
  <p>some text inside</p>
  <p>some text inside</p>
  <p>some text inside</p>
</div>

<br><br>
<button id='remove'>remove</button>
```

The remove button won't work in this case since there is no parent for all of the `.container-editor` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding the elements **after** `#list`, not inside it. So the first time you call `remove`, it works, because there is a `.container-editor` that is also the `:last-child` of its parent (the original one). But the ones you've added with the Add button are never the `:last-child` in their parent, they're followed by a couple of `br` elements. (Remember that `.container-editor:last-child` means "elements that have the class `container-editor` **and** are the last child in their parent element.")

In contrast, the jQuery `:last` extension doesn't care about whether what matches is the last **child**, just that it be the last one in the list.

You probably meant to insert those `.container-editor` elements **inside** `#list`, not after it. Change

```
$('#list').after(...
```

to

```
$('#list').append(...
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4m1k509h/3/)

Answer (score 2):

Because you are not adding the new elements to `#list`, so the first editor is the only editor which satisfies the `last-child` selector.

Instead of using `after` use `.append()` to add the elements like

```js
$('#add').click(function() {
  $('#list').append("<div class='container-editor'><p>some text inside</p><p>some text inside</p><p>some text inside</p></div>");
});

$('#remove').click(function() {
  $('.container-editor:last-child').remove();
});
```

```css
.container-editor {
  padding: .5em 2em 1.5em;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='list'>
  <div class='container-editor'>
    <p>some text inside</p>
    <p>some text inside</p>
    <p>some text inside</p>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<button id='add'>add</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button id='remove'>remove</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because first it was inside `#list` div and you're specifying its' `last child` so you need to append it inside `#list` div and then you need to apply.

```
$('.container-editor:last-child').remove();
```

You can use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
$('#list').append("<div class='container-editor'>
  <p>some text inside</p><p>some text inside</p><p>some text inside</p></div>")
```

Instead of

using [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

### [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/4m1k509h/4/)